# joining 3 tables or more with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let say I have 3 tables:

```
schools{id, name, desc, adress}
reviews{id, content, rating, school_id, user_id} # user_id & schoold_id is foregin keys
users{id, name, city}
```

How do I write a rails scope or method the joins all 3 tables and grab the column
the `schools.name` , `reviews.content` and `reviews.rating`, the `users.name`

I tried somehting this, but it only return the review data and not the joining part.

```
Review.joins(:school, :user).select("content, rating, schools.name, users.name").all
```

I am using rails 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define has-many :through relationships for schools and users like this:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :reviews 
end
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :schools
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many schools, :through => reviews
end
```

In your Review controller you can do

```
def index
  @reviews = Review.all
end
```

Then in your views each review object will have a school and a user associated with it, so you would just do:

```
review.content, review.rating, review.user.name, review.school.name
```

Reading this will help you understand why:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I have already defined that and I think you have misunderstood the question. I would like to join the tables not look for only one object model and it associations.

Comment: In order to retrieve all of the reviews you will just do @reviews = Review.all and each review will have the methods I described which will do *exactly* what your question asked.

Comment: @reviews = Review.include(:school, :user) will do the 3-way join.

Comment: But now I cant put sql functions on it, like how can I order them by DESC? or group them by an column.

Comment: Reviews.order("created_at DESC")